# javascript regex doesn't match ƒ character

Tags: javascript, regex, ascii

I have a requirement to only accept (extended) ascii characters. So I have a javascript regex like so:

```
/^[\x20-\xff]+$/.test("helloê¿£×Ø¬áƒ")
```

This *fails*. However, when I remove the funtion sign (159 in extended ascii) it accepts. That is strange, since á (160) and × (158) are fine, so it is accepting (some) extended ascii characters.

It feels like I'm missing something obvious here, but what?

Comment: What is your problem here? If you need to match the function symbol (`\u0192`), add it to the character class (`/^[\x20-\xff\u0192]+$/`), or revise the ranges you need to match.

Comment: BTW, there is nothing wrong with `á` (`\xE1`) and `×` (`\xD7`), they are in your range. Your code is working well and as expected.

Comment: problem was posting in IS-8859-1, which didn't have that character...

Comment: So, the question *is* off-topic. There was and is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was posting in ISO-8859-1, in which ƒ is not a character in the \x20-\xff range.
Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew